# How to check security acess (@Secured or @PreAuthorize) before validation (@Valid) in my Controller?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-security, controller

here is my Controller code :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('CREATE_USER')")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public UserReturnRO createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserRO userRO) throws BadParameterException{

    return userService.createUser(userRO);
}
```

My need is when a client without the appropriate role tries to create a user, the controller responds "Not authorized" even if the data sent are not valid. Instead of that, if the client (without the appropriate role) tries to create a user with wrong data, my controller responds with the @Valid message (ex : "password cannot be empty"), while I want it responds "not authorized".

In the `PreAuthorized` Interface we can find this sentence :

> Annotation for specifying a method access-control expression which will be evaluated to decide whether a method invocation is allowed or not.

but it seems that it's not the case.

Comment: The validation errors ALSO happen outside of the method - they are triggered by that Valid annotation which is - just like PreAuthorize - evaluated before the method is entered. i am not sure if it is possible to change the order there? my guess is - no. why would you want the 403 in either case?

Comment: because I don't want an not-authorized-user to access to the validation rules

Comment: ok. i wonder if @PreAuthorize would work if you put it on the validator?

Comment: Spring team already know this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10157

Answer (score 9):

You can not do this directly, since `@Valid` is processed *before* an actual method call and as a result *before* `@PreAuthorize`.

But what you can do instead is to inject `BindingResult` just right after your model (userRO) and in doing so - take control of validation process. Then check if `BindingResult` has some errors and if so return bad request response (similar to what spring does).

Example:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('CREATE_USER')")
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserRO userRO, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(result.getAllErrors());
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.createUser(userRO));
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but this behavior is absolutely weird (didn't they say "security first" ?).

Comment: 2023 still working, but still a strange solution to a strange problem. On the other, hand it just hides the request body validation error.

Answer (score 5):

As already stated, Spring Security's `@PreAuthorize` is method advice, which means that it does not get to participate until the method and its arguments have already been resolved.

Aside from [the answer already given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45947195/2243324), there are a few ways to move authorization before argument resolution, instead.

### Filter Security

First, Spring Security checks URLs before the request is mapped to a method. And since this is a `@Controller`, it's reasonable to suppose that you could instead map the request to the role at that level instead of `@PreAuthorize`:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .mvcMatchers(POST, "/somepath").hasRole("CREATE_USER")
```

### Handler Interceptor

Second, Spring MVC does ship with limited support for checking authorities before parsing method arguments. For example, you can do:

```
@EnableWebMvc
public static class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        UserRoleAuthorizationInterceptor userRole =
            new UserRoleAuthorizationInterceptor();
        userRole.setAuthorizedRoles("CREATE_USER");
        registry.addInterceptor(userRole);
    }
}
```

This is much more basic than `@PreAuthorize` since it's a global setting, but I've included it for completeness.

### Handler Interceptor, Part 2

Third (warning, some inelegance ahead), you can create your own `HandlerInterceptor`.

The flow is:

1. `FilterSecurityInterceptor` <== where `.mvcMatchers(...).hasRole(...)` lives
2. Then `HandlerInterceptor`s
3. Then argument validation
4. Then `MethodSecurityInterceptor` <== where `@PreAuthorize` lives

So, your `HandlerInterceptor` would check before arguments are resolved. It doesn't have to be as involved as `MethodSecurityInterceptor`, though. It could, for example, simply be:

```
static class AuthorizationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    SecurityMetadataSource securityMetadataSource;
    AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager;

    @Override
    public void preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {

        Authentication authenticated = (Authentication) request.getUserPrincipal();
        MethodInvocation mi = convert(handler);
        Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes =
            this.securityMetadataSource.getAttributes(mi);

        // throws AccessDeniedException
        this.accessDecisionManager.decide(authenticated, mi, attributes);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you wire it together with:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
static class MethodConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    HandlerInterceptor preAuthorize() throws Exception {
        return new AuthorizationInterceptor(
            accessDecisionManager(), methodSecurityMetadataSource());
    }
}

@EnableWebMvc
public static class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    AuthorizationInterceptor authorizationInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(authorizationInterceptor);
    }
}
```

It's inelegant because `MethodSecurityInterceptor` would still participate in authorized requests, which would ostensibly be the majority.