# Spring Security, Sprig Validation - change validation order

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-validator

In my Spring Boot application I have created Spring MVC Rest API which are secured with Spring Security(OAuth2) and use Spring Validation.

Right now I noticed one thing - when I'm trying to access the secure endpoint first of all I receive validation errors and only then(after I provided correct json in request body) security access denied error.

May be my question is silly but is it possible to place security check before input parameters validation ?

Comment: Here is similar post related to validation order http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28923360/how-to-make-preauthorize-having-higher-precedence-than-valid-or-validated

Comment: Do you have a code example?