# Custom ConstraintValidator is called even if user role not listed in @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot app with POST endpoint, @PreAuthorize role definition and a custom validator for the request body:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_OTHER')")
@RequestMapping(value = "post", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String post(@RequestBody @Valid DummyDTO dummyDTO) {
...
}
```

1) When I call the endpoint with **wrong role** and **non-valid request body** the custom validation code i.e. [ConstraintValidator.isValid()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html#isValid-T-javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext-) is executed and I **got 400 Bad Request**.

2) When I call the endpoint with **wrong role** and **valid request body** the custom validation code i.e. [ConstraintValidator.isValid()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html#isValid-T-javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext-) is executed and I **got 403 Forbidden**.

Why is the custom validation code executed before the @PreAuthorize check? I would expect to get 403 in both cases.

```
DEBUG 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Successfully Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken@bbd5887f: Principal: key; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
DEBUG 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@41ba74ef, returned: 1
DEBUG 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
DEBUG 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
DEBUG 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /post reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
 INFO 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.example.DummyValidator               : > isValid(): [valid]
DEBUG 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.lang.String com.example.MyController.post(com.example.DummyDTO); target is of class [com.example.MyController]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'hasAnyRole('ROLE_OTHER')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
DEBUG 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Successfully Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken@bbd5887f: Principal: key; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
DEBUG 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@356a19a2, returned: -1
DEBUG 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@7290b3e0, returned: 0
DEBUG 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@16f3e525, returned: 0
DEBUG 12776 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
...
```

---

My DTO:

```
public class DummyDTO {

@DummyConstraint
private String name;
...
}
```

constraint:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Constraint(validatedBy = {DummyValidator.class})
public @interface DummyConstraint {
...
}
```

and validator:

```
public class DummyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DummyConstraint, String> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DummyValidator.class);

    @Override
    public void initialize(DummyConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        LOGGER.info("> isValid(): [{}]", value);
        return "valid".equalsIgnoreCase(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also happens with Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780668/how-to-check-security-acess-secured-or-preauthorize-before-validation-vali