# How to check security access before validation (@Valid) in Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am creating a Restful API with Spring Boot 2.5 and would like to know the right way to implement validation while checking roles for some routes. Also, for some routes I need to make sure that only admins can modify the resource or its owner.

`@PreAuthorize` seems to be the solution, but `@Valid` seems to be processed before an actual method call, otherwise known as executed before `@PreAuthorize`.

See : [How to check security acess (@Secured or @PreAuthorize) before validation (@Valid) in my Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780668/how-to-check-security-acess-secured-or-preauthorize-before-validation-vali)

Is this really the only available and **clean** solution to make a Restful API with both validation and roles with Spring Boot & Spring Security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that that is the cleanest solution.
To check roles for some routes, you can configure your `HttpSecurity` to check roles before even getting to the controller, like so:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain app(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
        .antMatchers("/route1").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
    )
    return http.build();
}
```

So, with this configuration, you are making sure that only `ROLE_USER` or `ROLE_ADMIN` are allowed to request `/route1`.

But now, the `ROLE_USER` is allowed only if they are the resource owners. For this, you must have to resolve the method parameters to know which resource you are requesting. And then, in the `@PreAuthorize`, you can do something like this:

```java
@PreAuthorize("@myBean.isResourceOwner(resourceId, authentication)")
@PutMapping("/{resourceId}")
public void update(@PathVariable Long resourceId) {
    ...
}
```